# Joomla community builder

Tags: php, joomla, buddypress

I'm going to develop a travel social community; I'd like to understand if anyone has experience on community builder.

First, I'd like to understand if it has a good maintainability level.
Then, I read somewhere that it's affected by bad performance. Is it true?

I know it exists jomsocial, but I did not like the idea that it's a commercial product.
Any other chance?

What about buddypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a community driven website on Joomla, then Jomsocial is by far your best bet. Community builder is harder to use, not as intuitive for the user, and does not have near the feature set. It is a very good product, a great dev team, and large community. If you want to see how well it works, look no further than the official Joomla site - http://people.joomla.org/. I have used it for several sites and I am very pleased with it.

I wouldn't consider WP for any site other than a blog. While it can be extended, it is not really a framework designed as a platform for extensions. Joomla and Drupal are much more suited for that task. Once you go beyond a blog site, WP admin is not particularly elegant and can be unwieldy.

The cost of Jomsocial is a small price to pay for a high quality product.

Comment: if i decided to buy jomsocial, do they send me the source code too?? ie: i need to personalize the template or any other method, could i do that?

Comment: The extension is open source, plus it has a built in templating system so modifying and creating themes is very easy. It comes with several themes built in as well.